# Unicode Decode Error when trying to read csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8

I am new to python and stackoverflow.

- I have a folder with csv files and I am trying to read field name from each file and write them on new csv file.
- Thanks to stackoverflow, I was able to make and edit my code until unicode error came out.
- I tried my best trying to solve this error and did research.
- I found out that files created in Mac or Linux have utf8 unicode and files created in windows have cp949.
- Thus, I have to open them by utf8.

**My code first looked like this :**

```
import csv
import glob
lst=[]
files=glob.glob('C:/dataset/*.csv')
with open('test.csv','w',encoding='cp949',newline='') as testfile:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
    for file in files:
        with open(file,'r') as infile:
            file=file[file.rfind('\\')+1:]
            reader=csv.reader(infile)
            headers=next(reader) 
            headers=[str for str in headers if str] 
            while len(headers) < 3 :
                headers=next(reader) 
                headers=[str for str in headers if str]
            lst=[file]+headers
            csv_writer.writerow(lst)
```

Then this error came out :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\2.py", line 12, in <module>
    headers=next(reader)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Here is how I tried to fix unicode error :

```
import csv
import glob
lst=[]
files=glob.glob('C:/dataset/*.csv')
with open('test.csv','w',encoding='cp949',newline='') as testfile:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
    for file in files:
        try:
            with open(file,'r') as infile:
                file=file[file.rfind('\\')+1:]
                reader=csv.reader(infile)
                headers=next(reader) 
                headers=[str for str in headers if str] 
                while len(headers) < 3 :
                    headers=next(reader) 
                    headers=[str for str in headers if str]
                lst=[file]+headers
                csv_writer.writerow(lst)
        except:
            with open(file,'r',encoding='utf8') as infile:
                file=file[file.rfind('\\')+1:]
                reader=csv.reader(infile)
                headers=next(reader)
                headers=[str for str in headers if str]
                while len(headers) < 3 :
                    headers=next(reader) 
                    headers=[str for str in headers if str]
                lst=[file]+headers
                csv_writer.writerow(lst)
```

And this error came out :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\2.py", line 12, in <module>
    headers=next(reader)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence
```

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\2.py", line 20, in <module>
    with open(file,'r',encoding='utf8') as infile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2010_1_1.csv'
```

File `'2010_1_1.csv'` definitely exists in my directory `('C:/dataset/*.csv')`

When I try to open this file individually using `open('C:/dataset/2010_1_1.csv','r',encoding='utf8')` it works but there is '\ufeff' next to filename.

I am not sure but my guess is that this file is being opened in `try:` and not yet closed thus python can't open this file at `except`.

How can I edit my code to solve this Unicode problem?

---

```
import glob
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector
files=glob.glob('C:/example/*.csv')
for filename in files:
print(filename.ljust(60)),
detector.reset()
for line in file(filename, 'rb'):
    detector.feed(line)
    if detector.done: break
detector.close()
print(detector.result)
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 4, in <module>
    for line in file(filename, 'rb'):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: This is very poorly formatted.

Comment: @Nabin Sorry.. I tried my best but both my code and my question is messy.

Comment: for the `file not found` error, are you sure that your code is operating with `C:/dataset/` as its working directory? you can use `os.getcwd()` to find out. I'm not sure about the encoding.

Comment: @Stael Yes. Since it worked for 670 files, my code is operating with `C:/dataset/`.

Comment: Normally, the context manager (`with`) should close the file before entering the `except` block. But I cannot understand what you mean by *it works but there is '\ufeff' next to filename*. Could you elaborate on that, because I suspect it is the key of your problem (`'\ufeff'` is the unicode Byte Order Mark)

Comment: @SergeBallesta When I tried the code using try and except, that's the error I get. `FileNotFoundError`.  Therefore, I tried opening just one single file that caused error using `open(errorfile,'r',encoding='utf8')` then read file name and field names and save them as list. Normally it looked like this ['2012_budget.csv','plan','date','money'] but what I mean by `\ufeff' is that it came out like this ['\ufeff2012_budget.csv','plan'..]

Comment: The \ufeff indicated the file was in a Unicode encoding, probably UTF-8. Use `utf-8-sig` to read that file and automatically handle the BOM character.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I think problem here is that files that failed to run in `try` can not be read in `except`. When I just add `utf-8-sig` to `try`, it can't even read very first file. add `utf-8-sig` to except, same problem as what I wrote in question occur.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with Python so call me out of this is not possible, but you could simply attempt ignoring the encoding of the file when opening it. I'm a Java programmer and from my experience, encoding only needs to be specifyed when creating a new file, and not when opening one.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. But thing is that as I have mentioned above, it works when I do it separately. I do not know which files are causing error without manually checking them everytime my code stops. It just doesn't work when I want to do this work at once by using `try` and `except`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file is not written in `cp949` if it won't decode properly.  You'll have to figure out the correct encoding.  A module like [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) can help.

On Windows, when reading a file open it with the encoding it was written in.  If UTF-8, use `utf-8-sig`, which will automatically handle and remove the byte-order-mark (BOM) `U+FEFF` character if present.  When writing, the best bet is to use `utf-8-sig` because it handles all possible Unicode characters and will add a BOM so Windows tools like Notepad and Excel will recognize UTF-8-encoded files.  Without it, most Windows tools will assume the ANSI encoding, which varies per localized version of Windows.

Comment: I tried checking encoding of files just using `open` and result was that encoding of all files were `cp949` which was weird. When I checked out csv files that caused error by manually opening them on excel, their format was different from those files that worked. For example if (1,2) is NAME, every row of column 2 should be NAME but in some rows, instead of putting multiple names in just one cell(column2), each names were recorded in each columns from 2 to whatever, thus lengh of rows were different from each other.

Comment: I will try chardet to check out encodings again.

Comment: `open` doesn't  detect encodings, that's just the default on your system. You have to know the correct encoding of the file being opened.

Comment: Oh! ok. I will try `chardet`

Comment: I edited my question to upload a code trying chardet. Isn't this how I shoud do it?

Answer (score 0):

Error Comes Out in Form of Unicode Decode Error its just Somewhere Missed Decoding it Could be both due to Format is Not Supported in Decoding the Particular File or Decoding is perfect but Error in file while it was Written in Whatever Format it had been ex:>json,xml,csv....

The Only way to Avoid when Stuck in this Problem is to Ignore errors in Decode in first part of Code by using errors='ignore' argument in open():>

```
       with open('test.csv','w',encoding='cp949',newline='') as testfile:

#to         

       with open(r'test.csv','w',encoding='cp949',newline='',errors='ignore') as testfile:
                                    #or
            data = open(r'test.csv',errors='ignore').read()#read the file as a data
```

## if error persist check with diffrent encoding using errors='ignore'